# How to initialise model objects explicitly without json data in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my Model: Client

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    client_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

This is a method in my views.py

```
def importClientsFromCSV(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pathToCSV = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/portfolio.csv'
        with open(pathToCSV, 'rU') as csvfile:
             portfolioreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
             printer = "Number of Rows = "

             rows = 0
             for row in portfolioreader:
                  try:
                       client = Client.objects.get(client_code=row[0])
                       #Client Exists - Update Details
                       client.debit = row[2]
                       client.credit = row[3]
                       serializer = ClientSerializer(client)
                       if serializer.is_valid():
                           serializer.save()
                           rows = rows + 1
                       except Client.DoesNotExist:
                           client = Client()
                           client.client_code=row[0]
                           client.client_name=row[1]
                           client.debit=row[2]
                           client.credit=row[3]
                           serializer = ClientSerializer(client)
                           if serializer.is_valid():
                               serializer.save()
                               rows = rows + 1
             if rows > 0:
                  return HttpResponse(pathToCSV+", "+printer+str(rows),status=200)
             else:
                  return HttpResponse("Could Not Process",status=404)
```

The problem is I am facing is not able to add the client object that i create in Except block into my database. I am not sure why i am not able to serialize this object and save it.

Comment: Does your csv have a heading row, that it is reading in? Also is the for loop inside the `with open` statement as my editing has changed it?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new object you need to create your `ClientSerializer` without a `Client` instance and with the raw data instead.

```
serializer = ClientSerializer(data=dict_from_row)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

(You pass an instance when you want to serialise an object or an instance plus data when you want to update.)

Check out [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which would give you `dict_from_row` without further ado.

I hope that helps.